# How to check if file is under source control in SharpSvn?

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

Hi I use C# and SharpSvn library. I would like to check if file is under source control before adding it with SvnClient.Add. When I do it on file that already is under SVN than I get error : "is already under version control".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This pretty well demonstrates how to do it using status

```
using(SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    SvnStatusArgs sa = new SvnStatusArgs();
    sa.Depth = SvnDepth.Empty; // Adjust this to check direct files, or (recursive) directories etc

    Collection<SvnStatusEventArgs> statuses;
    client.GetStatus("c:\\somefile.txt", sa, out statuses); 

    Assert.That(statuses.Count, Is.EqualTo(1));
    Assert.That(SvnStatus.NotVersioned, Is.EqualTo(statuses[0].LocalContentStatus));
}
```

Comment: Checking with .GetInfo() is a bit cheaper (io-wise) if you only need to know if the file is under source control and not if the file is modified.

Comment: `.Status()` will do a file comparison if the file might have been modified, so worst case in case only the last byte of a 2 GByte file was modified it might almost read 2*2 GByte to determine this. With `.Info()` you are sure this never happens.

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to know if the file is under source control you could use `.Info()` / `.GetInfo()`. That method is generally faster as it doesn't have to check if the file has changed since it was checked out.

Comment: `.Status()` will do a file comparison if the file might have been modified, so worst case in case only the last byte of a 2 GByte file was modified it might almost read 2*2 GByte to determine this. With `.Info()` you are sure this never happens.