# Check to See if File is in Repository with SharpSVN

Tags: c#, .net, sharpsvn

How do I check if a file is already in a repository (or NOT in the repository) so I can determine whether I need to 'add' it first before doing the check in?  (For the record, I have check-in working, but I get an exception when I try to check in a file that has not yet been added to the repository.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if file is under source control in SharpSvn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868701/how-to-check-if-file-is-under-source-control-in-sharpsvn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While SvnClient.GetRepositoryIdFromUri may work (I wasn't able to get it working), I did [find an answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868701/how-to-check-if-file-is-under-source-control-in-sharpsvn) on SO which did work (this didn't come up in my original search, so sorry about the duplicate question).

Comment: I've used `GetRepositoryIdFromUri` for quite some time and had no issues so far. But today I realized that it fails if you use it with a previously in SVN deleted file. So deleting a file in SVN and recreating it on the file system will give you false results when using `GetRepositoryIdFromUri`. At least for me that was not the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [SvnClient.GetRepositoryIdFromUri](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/M_SharpSvn_SvnClient_GetRepositoryIdFromUri.htm) to verify that a specific file exists.  If that method returns false, then you'll need to Add the file to the repository.

Comment: I took a look at that.  However, when I pass the URL as a local string path (C:\Path\To\File.txt), the URI that is created seems incorrect.  Maybe I am just formatting the URI incorrectly?

Comment: You can use .TryGetRepositoryId(Uri, out Guid) for urls and .TryGetRepositoryId(string, out Guid) for local paths.

If you pass a local path to SharpSvn via a Uri, you pass a file:/// style url.

Comment: @Bert - Unfortunately, I am still getting back the System.Guid.Empty value as a response, even though the file is already in the repository.

Comment: Attempted to use .TryGetRepository(uri, out guid) to check if a bogus file exists on the remote repo and it both returned true and a non-empty guid. Does this method simply check if the patch is there and not the file? I see in the method summary `Gets the Uuid of a Uri, or System.Guid.Empty if path is not versioned`